# How to debug MSBuild Customtask

Tags: debugging, msbuild

I'm trying to debug the MSBuild Customtask, that I have just created, but for some reason it never stops at the breakpoint.  I've even tried this:

```
    public override bool Execute()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

And added a break point on that line... I even eliminated all the other code in the method and that didn't change anything.

Is there anything special required to be able to debug the creation of custom tasks for MSBuild ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but you could always just put this line of code wherever it is that you want to start debugging:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

When you invoke it, the CLR will launch a dialog asking you what debugger you want to attach.

Comment: That worked, but I don'o understand why Break() didn't ... thanks, atleast I can debug

Comment: i get an Unable to attach to the crashing process. The debugger is not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code. Run setup to install or repair the debugger. any suggestions on how to resolve? should i reinstall Visual Studio?

Comment: Even Debugger.Break(); works. Make sure you are compiling the application in Debug mode.

Comment: What if the problem is on the remote build server and the custom_task.dll is in release mode?

Answer (score 10):

This is what I do...  In the Project Properties dialog on the Debug Tab Select "Start an External App" - put C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe in the box..

Then in the command line parms, put your arguments /Target:Whatever test.proj

Put a code stop in your custom task and start the app..

Comment: i found that suggestion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/28/474951.aspx). i've played around with the concept but never really got it to work yet.

Comment: above link is broken

Comment: Link is archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160209232125/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/28/474951.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can set the environment variable `MSBUILDDEBUGONSTART=1` to make `MSBuild.exe` prompt to launch a debugger at its application startup.

You can then select the Visual Studio instance you're using to develop your task as the debugger, and set a breakpoint in your task's code.

This is generally a bit more difficult than modifying your task to call `Debugger.Launch()`, but it can be used on release builds and without modifying a task, which can be useful.

There's one major caveat here: when you build with `-m`, MSBuild will launch multiple processes, and *each of them* will prompt to attach a debugger. Try to build with `-m:1` or build single projects when doing this, so that you don't accidentally spawn dozens of processes that want to be debugged.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug the custom Task, you need the debugger to be attached to the MSBuild (or dotnet build) process.

I found an article that explains why `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` does not work.

What you can do instead as a workaround is use

```
SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => Debugger.IsAttached);
```

When you build the project that uses the custom task, it will not continue the build until there is a debugger attached. At which point, your breakpoint will then be able to be hit and you can step through the Task.

I found this from this article: [Implementing and Debugging Custom MSBuild Tasks](https://ithrowexceptions.com/2020/08/04/implementing-and-debugging-custom-msbuild-tasks.html)

Huge kudos to the author; because this had me stuck for quite a while.